# How to check in only a specific branch in TFS from batch?

Tags: batch-file, tfs, tfvc

I am using batch to check in to TFS.

Currently, I am using the following line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe" checkin  /noprompt /login:%un%,%pass% /comment:%1
```

How can I specify to only check in files to a specific branch?

Assume the branch name comes as input in %4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tf.exe checkin` command do checkin to your Pending Changes. if your changes are from specific branch so the checkin will be to this branch. you can't modify file in Branch `a` and do checkin to Branch `b`, you need to work on the file in Branch `b` to be able checkin back the changes.

You can copy the modified file/s and paste them in Branch `b` workspace, then do checkin.

If you want to checkin only one file, you can simply specify the file:

```
checkin c:/test.cs /noprompt ...
```

If you want to checkin only to specific branch (or location in the source control), just specify the server location:

```
checkin $/Project/Test/BranchA/* /noprompt ...
```

In your case:

```
checkin %4 /noprompt ...
```

**PS** - the `%4` must contains `/*` in the end (`$/BranchA` - not working, `$/BranchA/*` - working).

Comment: Thanks. What i meant was, if there was a change to both files a and b in branches A and B, how can i only check in file a to branch A, without checking in file b?

Comment: Oh ok, so is not problem, just specify the file path, see my updated answer.

Comment: I want to checkin all of the files in branch %4. I don't know their names.

Comment: So you need put the server path of the branch, see my updated answer :)

Comment: @Gulzar did you try it?

Comment: on it as we speak.